# Advantages and Disadvantages of using dbo in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

I am curious to know the advantages and disadvantages of using dbo in the stored procedures of sql queries

Comment: possible duplicate of [DBO rights risk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290236/dbo-rights-risk)

Comment: This question is extremely ambiguous.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. He simply wants to know if he should be using dbo or not in his sql queries and stored procs, but it's been asked before, see the dupe link

Comment: Interesting! I wish you luck in researching your curiosity. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have an *actual*, specific, programming-related question.

Comment: You mean the DBO. at the beginning of the name of SP's?
I think that is automatically added.

Comment: Hi @Tanner thank you for your help. I got some information on dbo but I would like to know more about it, like What difference does it make If I just select values from "tablename" instead of Select values from "dbo.tablename"

Comment: Check out this article. It will help clear up the confusion... I had the same question when I first started... Unless you are working with a complex/custom schema, then it does not matter. You can usually ignore the dbo. when addressing tables. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062075/why-do-table-names-in-sql-server-start-with-dbo

Comment: @Tanner_Gram awesome, thank you very much. I think this clears my confusion

Comment: Using explicit schema qualification (two part naming) can help with execution plan reuse in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is considered [best practice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx) (see How to Refer to Objects) to include the schema with the object name you are calling (EXEC dbo.MyProc).  This removes any ambiguity in the event you use multiple schemas.  This also prevents SQL from having to go and look up the object in its catalogs.  This should result in a minor performance gain, however impact may vary.